# How to add indexed integers to a vector?

Tags: c++

I have a textbook exercise that tells me to make a number guessing game. One of the bot questions is to check if user input is less than 50.

The following code using `{1}` prints '1' fifty times, but using `{i}` prints 1-100? I want to add numbers 0-50 to vector `blacklist`.

```
std::cout << "Is the number you're thinking of less than 50? (y/n)";
    std::cin >> userAnswer;
    if(userAnswer == "y") {
        for(int i=0; i<=50; i++) {
            blacklist.insert(blacklist.end(), {1});
        }
        for(int x : blacklist) {
            std::cout << x;
        }
    }
```

***Highlighted code above***

***Full code below, if necessary***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::string userAnswer, botQuestion {};
    int userInt, botGuess {};
    std::vector<int> blacklist {};

    while(userAnswer != "y") {
        std::cout << "Think of an integer between 1-100.:\nAre you ready? (y/n)";
         std::cin >> userAnswer;
        if(userAnswer == "y") break;
        else if (userAnswer == "n") {
            std::cout << "Hurry up then lmao\n ------------- \n";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Is the number you're thinking of less than 50? (y/n)";
    std::cin >> userAnswer;
    if(userAnswer == "y") {
        for(int i=0; i<=50; i++) {
            blacklist.insert(blacklist.end(), {1});
        }
        for(int x : blacklist) {
            std::cout << x;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you are surprised here.  `{1}` is a constant, it never changes, you'll get `1` in every iteration.  In `{i}` you are using `i`, and `i` gets increased by one every iteration, giving you an increasing sequence of values.

Comment: is there a way to insert int 1-50 without having to clutter up the code by manually typing 1 to 50, and without having to do the same with `push_back()`

Comment: @SILO Calling `push_back()` in a loop is the correct way. If you don't want to code the loop manually, use `std::generate/_n()` or `std::itoa()` instead.

Comment: "*The following code using `{1}` prints '1' fifty times*" - actually, 51 times. "*but using `{i}` prints 1-100*" - no, it doesn't, it prints 0-50, inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Use [std::iota](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota).

```
std::vector<int> blacklist(51);
std::iota(blacklist.begin(), blacklist.end(), 0); // fill blacklist 0-50
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using push_back(i) instead:

```
std::cout << "Is the number you're thinking of less than 50? (y/n)";
    std::cin >> userAnswer;
    if(userAnswer == "y") {
        for(int i=0; i<=50; i++) {
            blacklist.push_back(i);
        }
        for(int x : blacklist) {
            std::cout << x;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that you still have a potential off by one problem because `for(int i=0; i<=50; i++)` will allow `i` to range 0 .. 50 for a total of 51 items in `blacklist`